# curl + https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom = 401 Unauthorized

Tags: bash, curl, gmail, zsh

In the past I have successfully been able to access my Gmail account using `curl` in bash or zsh shell scripts, like this:

```
USERNAME='example@gmail.com'
PASSWORD='superSeckret'
URL='https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom'

curl -s -u "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" "$URL"
```

However, now when I attempt this, I get this error:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If I open https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom in a web browser, it shows the feed as expected, but I cannot get it to work via `curl`.

I tried looking to see if Google had shut down access to this, but I did not see anything that seemed relevant, but I still can't get it to work.

Is there another way to try this?

At minimum what I would like is to get a count of unread messages in my Gmail inbox.

Being able to see the From: and Subject: lines would also be nice.

(I have tried this both from my regular Gmail account as well as my work email which is a Google Suite/Google Apps address which has support for 'less secure apps' enabled. I am actually trying to do this for my work email.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/feed/atom is requesting HTTP Basic Auth login, but when given valid credentials, it says the creds are invalid... looks like the endpoint is broken, someone should send a bugreport to google

Comment: The code in this question is full of "fancy" unicode quotes, which will not work properly in shell scripts. I assume they're not actually that way in the script (or you'd be getting more obvious errors), but they should probably be corrected in the question anyway.

Comment: Weird. I have no idea how the 'smart' quotes got in there, but they are definitely not in the original. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

after some testing, it appears that to use this endpoint, you first have to try to log in, you will fail, then you must login to gmail normally, then go to https://myaccount.google.com/notifications and find your failed login attempt on the list, and cofirm `that was me` , after that the https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom endpoint should work again with just HTTP Basic Auth.. at least that's what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial & error, I have found a way that works.

I don't know *why* this way works and the other way (which used to work) doesn't.

I just know that as of 2021-03-03 this way works and the other doesn't.

## For Gmail

If your Gmail address is `example@gmail.com` then this will work

```
curl -sfLS "https://example:supersekretpassword@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"
```

## For Domains Hosted by Google

If your Google Suite/Google Apps/whatever account is `me@example.com` then this will work

```
curl -sfLS "https://me%40example.com:supersekretpassword@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"
```

Comment: any alternative without enabling "Less secure app access"?

Answer (score 0):

## The option "Less secure app access"

As soon as the option "Less secure app access" is turned off, you get a HTTP status 401 even with the correct credentials on the atom feed endpoint.

Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security to activate the option "Less secure app access" to make sure authentication succeeds again.

This option is automatically set to off after some time when not used, according to https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?p=less-secure-apps

## Using OAuth to authenticate

The smarter way to prevent those authentication issues would be to use OAuth protocol to authenticate: https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed

Comment: You can access that setting directly using this URL: <https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps> however if you have 2FA enabled (as I do) it will tell you that the feature is not available for 2FA accounts and you have to use an app-specific password.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use OAuth 2.0 for "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"

### Obtain "Client ID"

1. Create a project in https://console.developers.google.com/
2. Add "Test User" if you don't want to publish this app
3. Create OAuth 2.0 Client ID in that project
4. Obtain the client_id and client_secret

### Obtain "Authorization Code"

5. Replace [client_id] in this below URL with the obtained client_id and visit the link in a browser

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[client_id]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom&response_type=code
```

6. Obtain the authorization_code to get access_token

### Get Access Token

```
curl --request POST --data "code=[authorization_code]&client_id=[client_id]&client_secret=[client_secret]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

7. Obtain "access_token" and "refresh_token"

### Use access_token to access the mail atom feed

```
curl -H "Authorization: OAuth [access_token]" "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"
```

### Note

- if access_token is expired (1 hour), use refresh_token to get a new access_token

```
curl --request POST --data "--data '&client_id=[client_id]&client_secret=[client_secret]&refresh_token=[refresh_token]&grant_type=refresh_token" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```